# How do I link each modal window to the specific image that the user clicks on to open them?

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I've looked for solutions online and it seems that there's something called the `data-attribute` that I can use to do what I want.

I have two different modal windows, each with its own content, and I want to link each of them to a specific button (or in my case, an image that the user will click on). I tried putting in the "data-attribute", but the second modal window (the one with the id, `fujian`), is not popping up when I click on the corresponding image.

Does anyone have any suggests or ideas as to why this isn't working and what I should do?

```
<!--The two image icons that user clicks on-->
<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'><img src="city1.png" alt="sichuan" class="city1"/></a>
<a href='#' onclick='overlay()' data-target="#fujian" data-toggle="modal"><img src="city2.png" alt="sichuan" class="city2"/></a>

<div id="overlay">
   <!--The two separate modal windows-->
   <div class="modal">
       <img src="sichuan.png" alt="sichuan popUp"/>
       <a class="closing" href='#' onclick='overlay()'><img src="/Users/KarenLee/Desktop/exit.png"></img></a>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay">
   <div class="modal" id="fujian">
       <img src="fujian.png" alt="fujian popUp"/>
       <a class="closing" href='#' onclick='overlay()'><img src="/Users/KarenLee/Desktop/exit.png"></img></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is my `overlay()` function if you need to see it:

```
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Comment: What does your `overlay()` function do? Does it `return false;` or do anything that might stop the click from getting to the Bootstrap JS? I'm assuming you're using the Bootstrap framework here?

Comment: Oh! Let me edit my question to include the overlay() function. @WillshawMedia

Comment: Quickly copying and pasting your HTML into JSFiddle, then clicking the 2nd image the Modal overlay shows. https://jsfiddle.net/sk33fswg/. This is without your `overlay()` function being included. From that code alone it looks like the modal is triggered but the styling is off - the page isn't nested inside the bootstrap `.container` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `id's` must be unique through out the document and you have repeating id `<div id="overlay">`
2. You can achieve with single modal what you are trying to achieve with 2 modals with `data-attributes`
3. Missing key `div` elements in modal HTML and that's why with your code only modal-backdrop is showing, nothing else

as far you asked about `data-attribute`, the anchor `<a></a>` element has two custom data attributes: `data-toggle` and `data-target`. 
The toggle tells Bootstrap what to do and the target tells Bootstrap which element is going to open. 
So whenever `<a></a>` link like that is clicked, a modal with targeted `id` will appear.

let's suppose you have 2 images and wants to show in modal, opening modal with default bootstrap behaviour and also can pass the image to modal using `data-attributes` which in this case `data-image` and using [bootstrap modal event listener](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events), can show the image in modal when modal open (no need of 2 modals)

```
<a data-target="#fujian" data-toggle="modal" data-image="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/1.png" class="btn btn-primary">Image 1</a>
<a data-target="#fujian" data-toggle="modal" data-image="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/2.png" class="btn btn-warning">Image 2</a>
```

And Modal HTML will be

```
<div id="fujian" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog"> //Missing this Div
        <div class="modal-content"> //Missing this Div
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="showimage" src="" /> //Image will be shown Here
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and bootstrap event listener

```
$(document).ready(function () { //Dom Ready
    $('#fujian').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { //Event listener
        var image = $(e.relatedTarget).data('image'); //Fetch image url from modal trigger <a> link
        $(".showimage").attr("src", image); //load image in modal
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5b01x6g2/)